# Draw on PDF with javascript or C#

Tags: c#, javascript, pdf

I am looking for a way for a user to go to a webpage on there tablet, smart phone, or pc and view a pdf and then sign it with a pen tool.  Then I need to be able to save it.  I want them to be able to draw anywhere on the document, not just certain locations.  The PDF will vary in page length so I don't believe converting them to an image and back is an option(I could be wrong).

I am willing to use a third party tool even if cost something.  Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried iTextSharp?

Answer (score 0):

try [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/). its free as long as you don't use it commercially. It is a library for making pdf in c#

Comment: it's free as long as you ready to open source code of your solution.

Comment: Yes, the maddness of crowds is amazing. iText is NOT free - It is AGPL.

Comment: @Ika, you have a point but I think you are somewhat misunderstood. iTextsharp is free. They require a payment for the license if you use it commercially with respect to the AGPL. Gets?

Comment: Gets.. but AGPL!=FREE. Please read the license agreement. You need to do specific things (like share your app code) even for non-commercial apps etc. I talk to pissed developers every day who were fed this misinformation just to regret it later on.

Comment: I did not say that AGPL==FREE.

Answer (score 0):

If I got your requirements right, you need to add free hand drawings to a PDF file from a website.
You can do this by:
1- Generating a raster image from your PDF file and displaying it on a webpage.
2- Allowing free-hand drawings on your page and collecting the collection of connected points that result from the drawing.
3- Submitting the points to the server that contains the PDF file, opening the file with a PDF processing library, and adding a PDF annotation to it using the information you got from the browser.

You can do the step 1 with [ghostscript](http://www.ghostscript.com/) (GPL),or with [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) as a wrapper for ghostscript (GPL), or with a commercial library like [Amyuni PDF Creator](http://www.amyuni.com/en/developer/pdfcreator/features/) (*usual disclaimer applies*).

You can do the step 2 with an HTML5 canvas using Javascript

You can do the step 3 with almost every PDF processing library, for example with iTextSharp (AGPL) or again with Amyuni PDF Creator.

*Please not that you are not supposed to use GPL libraries in commercial closed-source application without paying anything.*